# Accessing data from an xml file

Tags: php, xml, web-services

I want to perform an if check on an XML file I have loaded in using `simplexml_load_file`.

I have accessed the data when the output is as I want it to be, although as it's web services sometimes they may be a response which I need to cater for.  The below is the XML I want to be able to check on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProductSizes />
```

Can somebody help me out? I am using the below:

```
$xmlstock = simplexml_load_file($xmlfeed);
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: what language? php, ruby, java? I think php, check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php all tutorials you need.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the xml source looks something like the following when actually populated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProductSizes>
    <ProductSize />
    <ProductSize />
    <ProductSize />
</ProductSizes>
```

You can get a count using the count() api call:

```
$xmlstock = simplexml_load_file($xmlfeed);

$hasProductSizes = ($xmlstock->ProductSize->count() > 0) ? true : false;
```

More info on the count() API via [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.count.php).